# Raspberry Piにて、 CMake Error: The source directory "/home/opencv" does not exist. というエラー

Tags: linux, opencv, raspberry-pi

Raspberry Piの画面です.

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

## スクリーンショットにあるターミナルの画面の転写

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../opencv_contrib/modules/ ../opencv/
CMake Error: The source directory "/home/opencv" does not exist.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

Comment: dirが無いだけですね。path間違えてません？
あと、画像で質問するのは好まれません。画像があると質問内容が分かりやすくなる場合はもちろんありますが...
エラーが発生して英語だと戸惑うのもわかりますが、google翻訳などにペタッと貼り付けるだけで自己解決できるような物も多いですよ。

Comment: あなたの投稿を読む人・回答する人の事も考えて、本文もできれば「○○をしたくて××を実行したが、こんなエラーが出ます」など、"日本語"での説明が欲しいところです。タイトルも単に「エラーが出ました」ではなく、具体的な説明を心がけましょう。質問の仕方についてはヘルプも参考にしてください。 - https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

cmakeコマンドを実行しているカレントディレクトリが`/home/pi`なのに対して、コマンドの引数に指定した `../opencv/` = `/home/opencv/`が存在しないというエラーです。